# Pydantic with a field of type ENUM

Tags: python, pydantic

I want to transform to lowercase, the value that comes to the model of a field that is of type ENUM, before it is assigned.

I show an example.

```py
class DeviceType(str, Enum):

    BASIC = "basic"
    PROFESIONAL = "profesional"

class Device(BaseModel):

    id: UUID
    model: constr(to_lower=True)
    created_at: datetime = Field(alias="createdAt")
    owner_id: UUID = Field(alias="ownerId")
    type: DeviceType


info = {..., "type": "Basic", ...}

device = Device(**info) # Error

info = {..., "type": "basic", ...}

device = Device(**info) # No Error
```

The same thing I do for the **model** field, I want to do for the **type** field. But since it is not of type string, I cannot do exactly the same.

What I want is to prevent the model from failing if the value is *Basic* or *BASIC*. And my ENUM type is *basic*, all lowercase.

I want to use something from pydantic as I use with the **model** field, use it for the **type** field.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using pydantic 1 [you can use a root_validator](https://docs.pydantic.dev/1.10/usage/validators/#pre-and-per-item-validators) with `pre=true`

```py
class DeviceType(str, Enum):

    BASIC = "basic"
    PROFESIONAL = "profesional"

class Device(BaseModel):
    type: DeviceType

    @root_validator(pre=true)
    def device_convertor(cls, values):
        if "device" in values:
           values["device"] = values["device"].lower()
        return values
```

If you know possibles values you can use `aenum` library:

```py
from aenum import StrEnum

class DeviceType(StrEnum):
    BASIC = "basic", "Basic", "BASIC"
    PROFESIONAL = "profesional"
```

for v2 you have [a whole new syntax](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/functional_validators/#pydantic.functional_validators.BeforeValidator)

Comment: I thought about using validation, even though I'm not actually validating anything. If there is no better way to lowercase the value that arrives at the ENUM, I will use this form. Thank you for your response.

Comment: I have added an example using aenum, it can fit your need if you know possible input values in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a variable, which is string as shown-

```
x=string(name of ENUM variable)
```

with name of ENUM variable replaced with the original name of your variable (like z). I hope this helps...

Comment: I cannot understand your example, could you extend the comment?

Comment: I just converted the ENUM variable to string and assigned its value to x. That is just like x=3                                           y=str(x)